# What is does this half filled circle status icon mean?

Tags: starfield

I'm playing *Starfield* on PC (Premium Edition, via Steam). When I open the data menu via the 'tab' key, I see the following status:

[image: Screenshot of status icon]

What does this half-filled circle status icon mean?

If I go to the status page by pressing 'B', it doesn't show any status effects. The icon does show up on the 'character' tab, but only because it's the same icon to show airborne resistance and it's unclear how it's related to the status icon (if at all):

[image: Screenshot of damage resistances]

What does this status icon mean on the data page?

Comment: How are you breathing? Are you in an environment without oxygen?

Comment: I'm on my ship. As far as I know it has a breathable atmosphere.

Answer (score 4):

You correctly note that the icon shown is the one for airborne-based hazards, as shown in your second image.

Check your watch HUD in the bottom--there may be a banner across it that indicates an affliction or ailment. Alternatively, open your Status view (<kbd>B</kbd> on PC) to see any current afflictions or ailments.

You can cure these by visiting a doctor and paying for treatment, or consuming the right Aid-type item, if one exists for that ailment/affliction.

Below is what I assume is a full list of afflictions/ailments and their treatments from [GamesRadar.com](https://www.gamesradar.com/starfield-afflictions-cures/). A doctor can cure any affliction or ailment for 500 credits, and can be found in most large settlements.

| Affliction/Ailment | Treatment(s) |
| --- | --- |
| Addictions | Junk Flush |
| Brain Injury | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Burns | Heal Gel, Heal Paste, Antibiotic Paste, Infused Bandages, Analgesic Poultice |
| Concussion | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Contusions | Bandages, Repairing Immobilizer, Infused Bandages, Analgesic Poultice |
| Dislocated Limb | Immobilizer, Repairing Immobilizer, Anchored Immobilizer |
| Fractured Limb | Immobilizer, Repairing Immobilizer, Anchored Immobilizer |
| Fractured Skull | Immobilizer, Repairing Immobilizer, Anchored Immobilizer |
| Frostbite | Heal Gel, Heal Paste, Antibiotic Paste, Infused Bandages, Analgesic Poultice |
| Heatstroke | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Hernia | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Hypothermia | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Infections | Antibiotics, Penicillin X, Antibiotic Paste, Antibiotic Cocktail, Analgesic Poultice |
| Lacerations | Bandages, Infused Bandages, Repairing Immobilizer, Analgesic Poultice |
| Lung Damage | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Poisoning | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Puncture Wounds | Bandages, Repairing Immobilizer, Infused Bandages, Analgesic Poultice |
| Radiation Poisoning | Injector, Snake Oil |
| Sprain | Immobilizer, Repairing Immobilizer, Anchored Immobilizer |
| Torn Muscle | Immobilizer, Repairing Immobilizer, Anchored Immobilize |

Comment: There's no data in the watch. And wouldn't an illness show in the character view? The icon has since disappeared with no interaction needed on my part, including taking medicine or sleeping.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Fair point--yes, they should appear on the status page (the B button for PC)--I have not played long enough to encounter it myself to confirm this, but I have seen the other ailment icons and they don't particularly match up (they're triangles on the watch HUD, not circles). Given that, I would think the icon shown there indicates a temporary environmental "condition". I will delete this answer in a bit after you've seen this comment (or edit it if I find out/play long enough to encounter it myself).

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Had you perhaps consumed an item that gave you a temporary buff to airborne hazard resistance? I don't yet know the consumables well enough but I wouldn't be surprised if there were some that buffed the various environmental resistance stats.

Comment: https://game8.co/games/Starfield/archives/421265 says it's resistance to airborne damage

Comment: @TimmyJim That's what it indicates when it's displayed on the stats view of a piece of apparel (see OP's second image), but what it's doing as an icon under the health bar is another matter.

Comment: I hadn't consumed any buff-giving items, no. I had recently switched apparel which gave me the airborne and radiation resistances in my screenshot, which is when i noticed the sudden presence of the icon. I don't think my clothing was related to the icon, though, since I'm still wearing the same clothes and the icon is gone, and there was only the airborne icon and not the radiation one in addition.

Answer (score 3):

The icon in the circle under the status indicates an **environmental hazard** that your **suit protection has exhausted** itself against.

Your apparel, space suit, helmet, and pack all contribute to a certain amount of resistance to various hazardous conditions. When you leave a sheltered area (your ship, a building via an airlock, etc.), that protection begins to degrade. Eventually that protection wears out completely and you become vulnerable to the hazard. As the protection wears down, your watch will start beeping faster and faster to indicate this.

Once your protection is exhausted, your watch will show the icon for the hazard you're no longer protected against. (There may be multiple hazards in a given location, and your protection against each will degrade at a discrete rate.) Further, your status in the data tab will also show the hazard icon.

Hazards will appear in a circular icon. If you then contract an illness or a condition, it will appear as a triangle.

The hazard in the original post was for an airborne hazard. You'll see this show up on planets where there's a sandstorm going on (eg. Mars.) Alternatively you may see it if you step onto a toxic vent. This hazard usually causes the lung damage condition.

Here is an example with a different environmental hazard: thermal. In the first screenshot, you can see my watch shows a circle with a teardrop in it -- that means my suit's protection against thermal environmental hazards has been depleted. You'll also see a small triangular icon with three droplets in it: this is the frostbite I contracted by spending extended time exploring in the freezing rain after my suit protection was exhausted. The second screenshot shows the data pane with the same icons.

[image: Screenshot of watch face showing circular hazard icon and triangular condition icon]

[image: Screenshot of data pane showing status conditions with same icons]

So, to summarize:

- circular icon indicates that you're exposed to a hazard that your suit is not protecting against; the icons match up with the suit/apparel resistances
- triangular icon indicates an illness or condition that you're suffering from

---

The above is what these symbols mean in general. The fact that I showed this on my status when I was in my ship's cockpit (a safe place) is probably a bug. (It's a Bethesda game, what did you expect?)

Comment: A bug is a decent idea, although I'm also curious why it's not the orange color of a normal 'protection exhausted' notice. But then again, bugs are not known for being sensible, especially Bethesda ones...